# Acer monitor stopped working after it was powered with 12 V AC supply instead of DC

Tags: display, power-supply

I have Acer monitor which was working perfectly. Then my cousin got confused with the wire and powered the monitor with cable which has 12 V AC as a supply. That power cable is used for woofers. Since the pin look alike he inserted it. Now even If i insert the preferred power cable it's not turning on. Please help me with this. What might be affected ? If it is possible to repair it by myself please let me know :)
Thank you

Comment: What model is the monitor? You can try leaving it unplugged for a few hours and testing again. If it still doesn't work, your best hope is that you just blew an internal fuse.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  I tried leaving it unplugged the whole day and plugged it with the original power supply but it didn't work. So mostly the fuse is blown. In order to fix it what are the steps to be performed. If you can please guide me.

Comment: Take it apart and look for a fuse near where the power enters the case or near the power supply. The older the monitor is, the easier this is to do. Newer monitors can have lots of tiny plastic clips and very fragile screens that can be easily scratched or broken. The older the monitor is, the easier this typically is to do. But it will require some electronics knowledge and experience.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This is the recent one so it may have tiny parts and Where I can find the replacement parts. Acer provides parts so ordering from there would be good option?

Comment: Until you know what the issue is, you can't really order parts, unless you want to guess that it's the power supply and order a replacement. That's probably about 75% likely to be the problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am sure that the power supply caused this problem. What do you recommend me ? Go to local technician and get it resolved ? or do it myself. For time being take its power supply issue. What is the estimate part cost for power supply?

Comment: If you're not comfortable opening up a modern monitor (and if you were, you probably would have already done it), taking it to a technician is probably a good idea. What model is this?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am very comfortable with working on these things but I wanted to know what part is effected. so I can get a good idea while opening it. This monitor is Acer LED 24' S242HL.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Hopefully I can figure this out.